# PowerShell command to query Exchange online autoreply configurations

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

We sync our local AD to Office 365.

I have been asked to get the out-of-office reply for users who are:

1. Disabled
2. Still have an Exchange mailbox.

I have some of the command but cannot figure out how to make it work:

```
$disabled = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Employees,ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local" -Filter { UserAccountControl -eq 514 } -Properties mail | Select-Object mail

foreach ($mail in $disabled) {
  Get-MailboxAutoreplyConfiguration -Identity $mail
}
```

Comment: `Select-Object mail` → `Select-Object -ExpandProperty mail`

Comment: Which part are you unable to figure out, and what doesnt work with the code. Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved without the call to AD via `Get-ADUser` cmdlet to get the list of disabled accounts. You can check the result of `Get-Mailbox` for the property `ExchangeUserAccountControl`. If the value is `AccountDisabled` then the account should be disabled in AD.

So that means you can do this :

```
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
      Where {
        $_.recipienttype -eq "UserMailbox" -and ` # make sure we only get user mailboxes
        $_.recipienttypedetails -eq "UserMailbox" -and ` # make sure we only get licenced mailboxes only, no shared mailboxes, no room mailboxes, etc
        $_.exchangeuseraccountcontrol -like "*accountdisabled*" # make sure we only get disabled user accounts
      } |
      Get-MailboxAutoreplyConfiguration | # we can pipe user mailbox object directly into this cmdlet (no need to go into a foreach loop)
      Format-List identity,autoreplystate,internalmessage,externalmessage # you can remove this and replace with Select then send to Csv or wherever you need
```

*That last line with `Format-List` is just for viewing (and should be changed if you want to send data to a file, for example), this data can have large output depending if a user has internal or external messages set or not.*

Please note that the above will return list of all Active Mailboxes in your Office365 tenant that :

1. have an Office365 UserMailbox (should be licensed mailbox)
2. is Disabled in Active Directory (AD account has `Enabled : $False`)

You can tell if the AutoReply messages are Active by looking at the `autoreplystate` value. It will either be `Enabled` or `Disabled`. So you can even add another `Where` clause to filter down to only those mailboxes that have `autoreplystate : Enabled` to only view mailboxes that have active auto replies set (based on your description, this was not clear if it was required or not).